# Google Search Appliance indexing MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, google-search-appliance

We are running GSA 7.2.0.G.114 trying to fetch data from MySQL DB.
However Connector 4.1.0 only support 
● Oracle 11g
● Microsoft SQL Server 2008
We cant use Out of the box (Content Sources > Databases settings) as that requires manual syn. 
Do you know how to Indix MySQL Database in GSA?

Thanks - Manju

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it? If you can connect to it using JDBC driver, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: As per GSA Connector 4.1.0 documentation it only support Oracle 11g and Microsoft SQL server. So we cant use connector. previous version of Connectors used to support MySQL. With GSA 7.2 we are wondering how to connect to MySQL DB.

Comment: GSA Connector 3.X are still compatible and supported with GSA 7.2 and 7.4, nothing prevents from using it.

Comment: I got confused reading connector 4.x documentation as it says it support GSA 7.2 or higher. @jeromegv will try Connector 3.x. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

"Support" typically means that it has not been fully tested by Google Engineering.  I believe it will work with MySQL but it may not have been fully tested so you would simply need to test it out and see if it works in your implementation.